# SQL How to restrict parent row from updates once child added?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I use foreign keys to prevent rows from being deleted in some SQL tables once a child uses the key.  However, now I want to be able to restrict any column of the parent table from updates once the child uses the key.

For example if the parent table is
[ID],[First Name],[Last Name]

And the child table is
[ListID],[Emp ID]

The foreign key prevents me from deleting or updating [ID] in the parent table however, it doesn't stop me from modifying [First Name].  Is there a way to set up foreign keys to prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your rdbms? You need `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger  ... but not sure if you want forbid every update on the table. You know people can change names?

Comment: No, my parent and child tables look nothing like this, I was just trying to easily illustrate what I'm attempting to accomplish - the prevention of updating select columns of a parent table if and only a child record is added that references the parents key

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

you could use instead of trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParentTable]
(
ID INT, FirstName VARCHAR(50), LastName VARCHAR(50)
)
go

CREATE table ChildTable(EmpID INT)

go

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ParentTable_InsteadOfUPDATE]
       ON [dbo].[ParentTable]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN


       DECLARE @ID INT, @FirstName VARCHAR(50), @LastName VARCHAR(50)

       SELECT @ID = INSERTED.ID,
              @FirstName = INSERTED.FirstName,
              @LastName = INSERTED.LastName       
       FROM INSERTED

    IF EXISTS(select top 1 1 from DBO.ChildTable Where EmpID=@ID )
    BEGIN

       IF UPDATE([ID]) OR UPDATE([FirstName]) OR UPDATE([LastName])
       BEGIN
              RAISERROR('These fields cannot be updated.', 16 ,1)
              ROLLBACK
       END    
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Update [ParentTable] SET FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName Where ID=@ID;
    END   
END
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_name ON parent_table INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE parent_table
    SET [FirstName] = I.[firstname]
       ,[LastName] = I.[lastname]
     FROM parent_table A
     INNER JOIN inserted B
        ON A.[ID] = B.[ID]
     LEFT JOIN child_table CT
        ON A.[ID] = CT.[ListID] -- or [EmpID] - am not sure about the relation
     WHERE CT.[LsitID] IS NULL  -- where the element from parent_table does not have element in the child table

END
```

Also, always try to handle the logic in triggers in batches in order not to hurt the performance.